# Different behavior of numpy transpose() with Ubuntu vs OSX

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, numpy

I'm running the following code on two different machines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# compute ids
coeff = np.dot(matrix1, np.transpose(matrix2))
```

where `matrix2` is a pandas dataframe.

They are both running version `4.0.6` of Anaconda. One is Ubuntu 16 the other is OSX. Under OSX the code runs just fine. Under Linux, I'm getting

> TypeError: transpose() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Numpy version is `1.10.4` in both cases. The error above is fixed with the following change:

```
coeff = np.dot(matrix1, np.transpose(matrix2.as_matrix()))
```

why?

Comment: hmm.. does `numpy.__all__.count("transpose")` give you `2`?  It does for me which would suggest that this is definitely a bug in numpy.

Comment: I get that 2 as well on 1.11.0.  Without `pandas`.  `np.transpose` delegates action to `matrix2.transpose(axis)` if possible (`axis=None`).  I wonder if there's a problem with the `pandas` version of `transpose`.  The fix points to  `pandas` rather than `numpy`.

Comment: I wonder if `np.dot(matrix1, matrix2.transpose())` works?  or `matrix2.T`.

Comment: matrix2.transpose() does not work either. matrix2.T works, on the other hand